# End conversation in chatbot

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def send():
        send = "You: " + e.get()
        txt.insert(END, "\n" + send)

        user = e.get().lower()

        if (user == "hello" or user == "hi" or user == "hey" or user == "oi" or user == "halo"):
                txt.insert(END, "\n" + "Rob: Hi there, how can I help you? \n 0.Contact seller directly \n 1.Order Tracking \n 2.Refund and Return \n 3.HELP \n Please enter a number.")


        elif (user == "whats your name?" or user == "what is your name" or user == "name" or user == "you called" or user == "what is your name?"):
                txt.insert(END, "\n" + "Rob: My name is Rob.")

        elif (user == "0"):   ** **

                
        elif (user == "1"):
                txt.insert(END, "\n" + "Rob: Your bag has arrived. \n 00. Homepage \n 01. ** \n 0. ** **")

        elif (user == "4"):
                txt.insert(END, "\n" + "Rob: Damage and Broken \n Sorry for the inconvenient. Please take a photo of your item and send it to seller as soon as possible. Thank you.\n 00. Homepage \n 01. ** \n 0. ** **")
```

I am learning to creating a simple Tkinter GUI chatbot
Problems I am facing:

** ** = I want to end the conversation when user enters 0, and it will close this conversation and move to another python file.

** = when the user enter 01, chatbot will say goodbye and close the conversation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method to end in python you can just use return. In your ** ** case just type `return` under the if statement and it will ends. And in your ** case you just print goodbye or so and then use `return`.